# How to debug Spark application locally?

Tags: apache-spark

I would like to learn Spark step by step and wonder how to debug a Spark application locally? Could anyone please detail the steps needed to do this?

I can run  the simpleApp on the spark website locally from the command line but I just need to step through the code and see how it works.

Comment: I dont really know what do you mean by 'learning to debug'. You can look at this tutorial how to set up spark locally in IntelliJ ide https://docs.sigmoidanalytics.com/index.php/Step_by_Step_instructions_on_how_to_build_Spark_App_with_IntelliJ_IDEA.

Comment: I mean "how can I step through the SimpleApp application on the spark website. There is the SimpleApp.java file, and the pom.xml (as coded on the spark website). How can I use Intellij IDE to step line by line thorugh the code in SimpleApp.java and see what each line actually does? I want to be able to do this without sending the job to a cluster. I just want to step through the code on my laptop, locally. The link you provided gives the steps to build Spark App with IntelliJ IDEA. How about stepping through the code line by line? Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I dont know about scala but at least in java you can use standard IDEA debugger (in local mode). One thing u have to remember if you have big collection you will have to step throu all elements.

Answer (score 41):

Here's how I do it using IntelliJ.

First, make sure you can run your spark application locally using `spark-submit`, e.g. something like:

```
spark-submit --class MyMainClass myapplication.jar
```

Then, tell your local spark driver to pause and wait for a connection from a debugger when it starts up, by adding an option like the following:

```
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
```

where `agentlib:jdwp` is the Java Debug Wire Protocol (JDWP) option, followed by a comma-separated list of sub-options:

- `transport` defines the connection protocol used between debugger and debuggee -- either socket or "shared memory" -- you almost always want socket (`dt_socket`) except I believe in some cases on Microsoft Windows
- `server` whether this process should be the server when talking to the debugger (or conversely, the client) -- you always need one server and one client.  In this case, we're going to be the server and wait for a connection from the debugger
- `suspend` whether to pause execution until a debugger has successfully connected.  We turn this on so the driver won't start until the debugger connects
- `address` here, this is the port to listen on (for incoming debugger connection requests).  You can set it to any available port (you just have to make sure the debugger is configured to connect to this same port)

So now, your `spark-submit` command line should look something like:

```
spark-submit \
  --name MyApp \
  --class MyMainClass \
  --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
```

Now if you run the above, you should see something like

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
```

and your spark application is waiting for the debugger to attach.

Next, open the IntelliJ project containing your Spark application, and then open "Run -> Edit Configurations..."  Then click the "+" to add a new run/debug configuration, and select "Remote".  Give it a name, e.g. "SparkLocal", and select "Socket" for Transport, "Attach" for Debugger mode, and type in "localhost" for Host and the port you used above for Port, in this case, "5005".  Click "OK" to save.

In my version of IntelliJ it gives you suggestions for the debug command line to use for the debugged process, and it uses "suspend=n" -- we're ignoring that and using "suspend=y" (as above) because we want the application to wait until we connect to start.

Now you should be ready to debug.  Simply start spark with the above command, then select the IntelliJ run configuration you just created and click Debug.  IntelliJ should connect to your Spark application, which should now start running.  You can set break points, inspect variables, etc.

### Spark Shell

With `spark-shell` simply export `SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTS` as follows:

```
export SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
```

Attach to `localhost:5005` using your debugger (e.g. IntelliJ IDEA) and with the Spark sources imported, you should be able to step through the code just fine.

Comment: The full command line missed `-` before `agentlib`. I can't edit because of not enough character change.

Answer (score 10):

Fire up the Spark shell. This is straight from the [Spark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/):

```
./bin/spark-shell --master local[2]
```

You will also see the Spark shell referred to as the `REPL`. It is by far the best way to learn Spark. I spend 80% of my time in the Spark shell and the other 20% translating the code into my application.

Comment: What if the application is written in Java?

Comment: The Scala spark-shell can load Java jars, then you can run your app and or methods from Scala.

Comment: This is not very useful if you are building a (larger) function that you change all the time, and which you need to test in the shell. You need to re-import that function every time after you improved it. But that requires stopping and starting the shell (every time!), which is not a fast way of building code. The OP is asking for (python) ipdb-like functionality (obviously only useful in local mode), which apparently does not exist.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can define the function in a script and then import that into the shell. The shell will let you import the same function or collection or functions/classes/objects etc over and over and over. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 7):

Just pass java options to open debug port. Here is nice article addressing your question - http://danosipov.com/?p=779
I'm using it like

```
$ SPARK_JAVA_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 spark-shell
```

(yes, SPARK_JAVA_OPTS is deprecated, but it works fine)

Comment: I also stumbled upon the article you mentioned, however the SPARK_JAVA_OPTS didn't work for me in such a form. I had to modify it and what did it for me was: `export SPARK_JAVA_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=5005,suspend=y,onuncaught=n`

Answer (score 3):

@Jason Evans's answer did not work for me. But

```
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8086,suspend=n
```

worked

Comment: Yes, there was a "-" missing before "agentlib" as pointed out by @ryan, fixed now

Answer (score 2):

only one minor change is needed for @Jason Evan's answer. It needs a ‘-’ before the String "agentlib...."

```
 --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
```

you might also use the option "--driver-java-options" to achieve the same purpose

```
--driver-java-options -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct @ryan about the missing "-", thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can try this in `spark-env.sh`:

`SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8888`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly pick a version of spark then pick an IDE, intellij would be better. Checkout the source code of this spark version and make sure you can successfully build it from IDE(more [here](https://spark.apache.org/developer-tools.html)). once you have a clean build, search for the test cases or test suites. For example "SubquerySuite" is a simple one then debug it like a normal application. Comment about any specifics steps you need help with

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to get everything on the console:

First check here to see what level of info you want spark (log4j) to print on your console:

https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-logging.html

Then submit your command as follows:

```
path/to/spark-submit
  --master local[a number of cores here from your CPU]
  --driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/path/to/log4j-driver.properties 
  -Dvm.logging.level=ALL"
```

"ALL" will give you all the info you can get. Also it does not matter if spark does not find your log4.properties file, it should load the setting of your desired logging level and the info will print on your screen.