# How to debug a java-spark application?

Tags: spark-java

Is it possible to connect to a live Java-spark application and debug it using something similar to how you debug a Tomcat web service (for tomcat debug mode, for example: catalina jpda start)?

The goal is being able to attach to the java-spark micro-service and step through the source code while it's running.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I debug spark application locally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30403685/how-can-i-debug-spark-application-locally)

Comment: @JiriS i think the author is interested in the spark framework, not apache spark. Morkus, correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

you debug a [java-spark](http://sparkjava.com/) application just like you would debug any other Java application. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22631355/804521)

Comment: I'll give that a try. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

A standard Java debugger is the most powerful, but you there is also a dedicated project which provides a debug-page: https://github.com/perwendel/spark-debug-tools

Answer (score 0):

I'd write a Junit test that calls your function / class that you want to debug, take a sample of the input data that you believe is causing the issue and make that your input. Step through the code line by line, add in lots of shows :)