# spark-submit with -agentlib:jdwp doesn't suspend

Tags: java, apache-spark, debugging

I read answer from [How to debug Spark application locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30403685/4652536), here is my situation:
win10 + spark 2.3.2(compile using `mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.7 -Dhadoop.version=2.7.3 -Phive -Phive-thriftserver -DskipTests clean package`) , a hadoop cluster from docker, I execute command in spark's bin directory using cmd:

```
spark-submit  --name spark-test --class WordCount --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster  --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005  d:\dev\spark-test.jar   /data/data.txt
```

Unfortunately, "Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005" not appear, it went through SparkSubmit until throwing some exceptions. I check spark-class2.cmd ,it actually executed :

```
java -cp "xx" org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005" --class WordCount --name spark-test d:\dev\spark-test.jar /data/data.txt
```

so what do I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I mentioned is not complete:"--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-agentlib:jdwp.." only for client mode(at least in spark 2.3.2).
If you look carefully at my question: the --conf parameter passed to spark-submit also appear as --conf parameter in java command. It needs to append

> -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005

directly to java command. Here is my solution,put below in spark-env.cmd(windows):

```
SET  SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
```

spark will pick this up even in cluster mode.