# How to debug Spark when I am using PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My application (code that initializes spark session and call execution) runs in Python because I have some python UDFs. I have now made some changes to the spark source code, I wonder how can I debug spark source code if spark is launched from Python script.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30403685/how-to-debug-spark-application-locally) is a very similar question, in which the application is launched through spark-submit and a debugger is attached. However, this example only works for Java application. I wonder can we do the same thing if our application runs in Python.